# Intersecting redis sets that are incomplete

Tags: redis

I have some data that I want to store in redis to be able to efficiently intersect it. Example data:

```
 key |  members
---------------------------------
 101 |  "a1", "a2", "a3"
 102 |  "a2", "a3"
 103 |  "a2", "a4"
```

So, the intersection of those keys would give me

```
SINTER 101 102 103
1) "a2"
```

However, I have some problems when the dataset is incomplete:

```
 key |  members
---------------------------------
 101 |  "a1", "a2", "a3"
 102 |  "a2", "a3"
 103 |  "a4", "a5"
```

In this case, getting an intersection of the same three keys would give me an empty set:

```
SINTER 101 102 103
(empty list or set)
```

My goal is to get the member that matches most sets. Is there a way in redis to achieve this? I could alter the way my datasets are stored, if that helps. I.e. creating inverse versions of the sets (members as keys, keys as members)

Also, would it perhaps make sense to use some other key store than redis, which might be more suitable to this task?

Comment: What's if set `101` contains `a` and `b`, set `102` contains `b` and `c`, and set `103` contains `c` and `d`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with Union operations on sorted sets, using the AGGREGATE SUM argument. It's a bit clunky but it will work. Basically add all elements with a score of 1, and then union by summing up the scores.

The resulting set will be sorted from the element with the most intersection points to the element with the least:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd foo 1 a
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd foo 1 b
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd foo 1 c
(integer) 1

127.0.0.1:6379> zadd bar 1 a
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd bar 1 c
(integer) 1

127.0.0.1:6379> zadd baz 1 d
(integer) 1

# Now let's do the union and store it into "merged"
127.0.0.1:6379> ZUNIONSTORE merged 3 foo bar baz AGGREGATE SUM
(integer) 4

# Merged is now sorted by common points
127.0.0.1:6379> ZREVRANGE merged 0 -1 WITHSCORES
1) "c"
2) "2"
3) "a"
4) "2"
5) "d"
6) "1"
7) "b"
8) "1"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Comment: @Sævar keep in mind that if you have many big sets, the performance is terrible. it needs to traverse every element in every set.

Comment: Elegant solution! Also be careful with the following case: the score of all items in the merged set is `1`.